# How to use vue localization in wordoress plugin

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, plugins, vue-i18n

I have been developed a wordpress plugin along with vue js. Right now i want make this plugin multi lingual.
Can you guys please helps me out to how i can use vue i18n in wordpress plugin.

I tried to use wp-vue-i18n. But still failed because of proper documentation.

Comment: i18n for Vue on WordPress? How do you use Vue in that context? Usually, i18n is done on the client-side, otherwise you probably already have something related on WordPress' side, no need to try a Vue specific package. Or do you have something mixed up between WordPress and Vue in the same dashboard?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.